# Can sidebars impose on content (instead of overlaying)

Tags: react-admin

Is there a parameter or simple CSS change which would allow the sidebar to sit aside the existing view container, hence compressing it horizontally.

We have a project where overlaying covers an important piece of information that the user would want to see whilst entering content in the sidebar form

Comment: Which sidebar are you talking about? Is it the left sidebar for the menu? Or an `aside` on a List or Edit view?

Comment: Sorry (not dev asking the question) an aside I guess (the one the slides over from the right!